# Como manipular parte do atributo href de um link usando JavaScript no WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

É possível manipular apenas uma parte da URL usando DOM ou algo do tipo?

Gostaria de remover o '#' no meio da url, no atributo href.

O código será adicionado em um tema Wordpress e deve ser ativado ao carregar a página.

Como está atualmente:

```
<div class="rodape">
   <a class="azul" href="http://site.com/departamento/#consultoria-um"
   title="Detalhes">Detalhes</a>
   <a class="azul" href="http://site.com/departamento/#consultoria-dois"
   title="Detalhes">Detalhes</a>
</div>
```

Resultado final (sem # no link):

```
<div class="rodape">
   <a class="azul" href="http://site.com/departamento/consultoria-um"
   title="Detalhes">Detalhes</a>
   <a class="azul" href="http://site.com/departamento/consultoria-dois"
   title="Detalhes">Detalhes</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Você quer remover somente o '#'? ou ele e tudo o que vem após ele? isso é ao abrir a página ou após executar alguma ação específica?

Comment: De onde vem esse HTML? Podes manipular no servidor?

Comment: Quero remover apenas o # ao abrir a página. É um tema no Wordpress hospedado em servidor próprio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um jeito diferente:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.rodape a').forEach(function(el) {
  el.setAttribute('href', el.getAttribute('href').replace('#', ''));
  console.log(el);
});
```

```html
<div class="rodape">
   <a class="azul" href="http://site.com/departamento/#consultoria-um"
   title="Detalhes">Detalhes</a>
   <a class="azul" href="http://site.com/departamento/#consultoria-dois"
   title="Detalhes">Detalhes</a>
</div>
```

Uso o seletor `.rodape a` para pegar todos os anchor dentro da div com a classe rodape, e faço um loop com os elementos, dai tiro o # com a função `replace` e atualizo o atributo `href` com o link formatado.

Comment: JuniorNunes, testei e vi que deu certo em uma página comum, mas quando adiciono no Wordpress não funciona, sabe o que pode ser? Testei direto no código e posteriormente em plugins que inserem js na tema e nada.

Comment: @Grego tenta colocar o código dentro de: window.onload = function() { // codigo aqui }

Comment: Deu certo, muito obrigado! Salvou uma vida, hahaha.

Comment: @Grego se a resposta funcionou marque ela como solução ao lado esquerdo para que outras pessoas sejam ajudadas!

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível fazer isso capturando o valor do atributo `href` e manipulando-o.

Exemplo funcional

```js
document.getElementById('bt-remover-hashs').addEventListener('click', removerHashtags);

function removerHashtags(){
  var links = document.getElementById('rodape').getElementsByTagName('a');

  for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){  
    links[i].href = links[i].href.replace('#', '');  
    console.log(links[i].href);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="rodape" id="rodape">
   <a class="azul" href="http://site.com/departamento/#consultoria-um"
   title="Detalhes">Detalhes</a>
   <a class="azul" href="http://site.com/departamento/#consultoria-dois"
   title="Detalhes">Detalhes</a>
</div>

<button id="bt-remover-hashs">Remover #</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso utilize `jquery` segue o código:

```
newlink = $(".azul").attr("href").replace("#","");
$(".azul").attr("href",newlink);
```